# Stash - merge two lists

Tags: stash, 2.9

I need to merge to loops into one stash list.

The first loop is a standard channel entries loop.
The second is a twitter time line, using CE Twitter.(http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet)

Here is my code thus far, I've removed a lot of the markup and variables et al...

```
{!-- set list --}
{exp:stash:set_list name='journal_list' parse_tags='yes' depth="2" parse="inward"}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="journal" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" sort="desc" limit="10"} 
        {!-- append to the list the channel entries --}
        {exp:stash:append_list name='journal_list' parse_tags='yes' depth="2" parse="inward"}
                {!--type set as post, used to output post markup --}
                {stash:type}post{/stash:type}
                {!-- entry date saved to variable - the idea is to then use this as the order by argument --}
                {stash:entry_date}{entry_date}{/stash:entry_date}
                {!-- All the usual gubbins, titles, images, text et all, all sorted in stash variables --}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}

    {/exp:channel:entries} 

    {exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline screen_name="myMegaTwitterAccount" count="5" sort="asc"}
        {!-- append to the same list as above for the twitter time line --}
        {exp:stash:append_list name='journal_list' parse_tags='yes' depth="2" parse="inward"}
                {!--type set as tweet, used to output tweet markup --}
                {stash:type}tweet{/stash:type}
                {!-- entry date saved to variable - the idea is to then use this as the order by argument --}
                {stash:entry_date}{created_at}{/stash:entry_date}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}

    {/exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline}

{/exp:stash:set_list}


{exp:stash:get_list name='journal_list' order_by="{entry_date}" paginate="bottom" limit="5"}
    {if "{type}" == "Post"}
        {!-- all the post markup here --}
  {if:else}
    {!-- all the tweet markup here --}
  {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The code above works, but not quite right.

Currently the two lists are outputted separately, i.e. first all of the channel entries are outputted, then all the tweets.

What I need is for the sort order to be based solely on the {entry_date}, so the tweets and posts will be mixed up... [post post tweet post tweet post post] etc etc

I'm sure this will be possible, I may have approached this incorrectly.  Fairly new to stash, although I have to say I'm bloomin' loving it (Thanks Mark!)

I've added a screenshot below which should illustrate the issue I have, notice the dates on the items. eeee! (n.b using masonry for the layout)

Any help, greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: I would think a good place to start would be comparing the format of the two (different) fields you are using for `{stash:entry_date}` - your approach relies upon these being similarly scaled numbers, but if this assumption is not true (silly example, but if each was using a different year for the date) it would explain why they are being output in the order you see.  Might be worth doing a quick test that just lists out the title and date (in order) to see if dates are indeed of the same type...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by setting a list with the channel entry output and just appending the tweet module output to that list. A couple of other things, you have depth of 2 which adds processing and shouldn't be necessary in this case. (this is untested):

```
{!-- set list --}
{exp:stash:set_list 
    name='journal_list' 
    parse_tags='yes' 
    parse="inward"
}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="journal" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" sort="desc" limit="10"} 
        {stash:type}post{/stash:type}
        {stash:entry_date}{entry_date}{/stash:entry_date}
    {/exp:channel:entries} 
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline screen_name="myMegaTwitterAccount" count="5" sort="asc"}
    {!-- append to the same list as above for the twitter time line --}
    {exp:stash:append_list 
        name='journal_list' 
        parse_tags='yes' 
    }
        {stash:type}tweet{/stash:type}
        {stash:entry_date}{created_at_relative}{/stash:entry_date}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline}

{!--output the list--}
{exp:stash:get_list 
    name='journal_list' 
    order_by="{entry_date}" 
    paginate="bottom" 
    limit="5"
    process="end"
}
    {if "{type}" == "Post"}
        {!-- all the post markup here --}
    {if:else}
        {!-- all the tweet markup here --}
    {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

I added a process=end to the get_list, but depending on how you have the templates set up you may not need that. Also, the ce_tweet module tag may need to be wrapped with stash:parse  so that it runs after the initial set_list. If that's the case, you would use:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="inline" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline screen_name="myMegaTwitterAccount" count="5" sort="asc"}
        {!-- append to the same list as above for the twitter time line --}
        {exp:stash:append_list 
            name='journal_list' 
            parse_tags='yes' 
        }
            {stash:type}tweet{/stash:type}
            {stash:entry_date}{created_at_relative}{/stash:entry_date}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this over the weekend.  Appreciated

Comment: Hello, (been away for a while)... Still no joy with this... All the journal items are outputted, then the tweets. Rather than being spat out in date order. Any thoughts